# A PHP API for retrieving Mail From Yahoo, GMail, Hotmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, yahoo, hotmail

There are a few APIs for grabbing the address book/contact list from the major providers of email.

I was wondering do APIs like this exist for grabbing emails/messages received?

Thanks all

### EDIT

I am sure I can do this myself. However, I don't want to "re-invent" the wheel if someone has done it already. Probably better than I can since I am just a noob :P

Comment: Can you post a link to thoese API's for grabbing the addres book/contact ? It will be quite useful.

Comment: Google:  http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2008/03/3-2-1-contact-api-has-landed.html
Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/addressbook/
Hotmail: http://developer.yahoo.com/addressbook/

Comment: Is hot mail the same one as Yahoo?

Comment: Sourceforge baby http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber/ :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all of this services provide POP/IMAP protocol which you can acces with PHP's functions: http://php.net/book.imap

Comment: You might also want to check out the email related classes in PEAR, ezComponents and ZendFramework.