# how to import mails/contacts from gmail /yahoo etc?

Tags: php, email

Its like i want to import my all mails at one place. php is my end. Can anybody tell me how to implement this.I just want need the basic funda.. what are various libraries i should use.
Any suggestions and things not to do.Thnks..

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program to fetch your messages through mail protocol however, basic yahoo subscription does not allow this. In gmail you have to open this functionality from options. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463410/a-php-api-for-retrieving-mail-from-yahoo-gmail-hotmail) question.

Answer (score 0):

For gmail contacts You should check this: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/contacts/

Answer (score 0):

Mail can be retrieved using [**IMAP**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

IMAP must be [enabled on gmail accounts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725)

You could also look at this  [tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap)