# retrieve email address from inbox

Tags: php, email

Services as linkedin, facebook, etc, can import email addresses(contacts) from my Inbox if I provide my gmail/yahoo password. How are they doing it? Can I do it too, using PHP?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Contacts Data API](http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2008/03/3-2-1-contact-api-has-landed.html) allows you to own your own contact data. We expect the API to be useful for a big range of applications. For example, developers can use it to:

> - Import a user's Google contacts into their web or desktop application
> - Export their application's contact list to Google
> - Write sync applications for mobile devices or popular, desktop-based
>     contact management applications

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You need imap extension to make your live easier.
Here is sample example howto do this for gmail. Yahoo should be similer if not same.

http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Hope that helps.
Cheers

Edit: Got questions wrong.sry

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libgmailer](http://gmail-lite.sourceforge.net/wordpress/index.php/about/libgmailer/) for accessing Gmail in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use the [google contacts API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/).

Answer (score 0):

[ContactGrabber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber/) looks like it should work for GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail and other services.

[A PHP API for retrieving Mail From Yahoo, GMail, Hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463410/a-php-api-for-retrieving-mail-from-yahoo-gmail-hotmail)